# Ubuntu 18.04 / Dell Precision 5520 - New install, no video over Thunderbolt 3

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 18.04

Last night decided to try Ubuntu 18.04, did a fresh install on my laptop (previously had kubuntu 17.10 running).

I use a setup with two external monitors- 1 HDMI and 1 with Thunderbolt3 to display port. Now, I can no longer use my monitors.
If I plug in JUST the HDMI, the hdmi monitor is detected and works.
If I plug in BOTH external monitors, NEITHER monitor is detected.
If I plug in JUST the Thunderbolt, it is not detected.

Interestingly, if they are plugged in during boot, the Ubuntu splash screen briefly appears on the Thunderbolt monitor, and disappears before the login prompt appears. This setup was working correctly on Kubuntu yesterday. I tried installing the nvidida drivers with no change, updated to the latest firmware, and am not sure what the next step should be.

The only changes I have made to the system are installing Chrome and Wavebox and updating the drivers as described... stock install from the ISO otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Turned out I had MST enabled on the Thunderbolt monitor... but there was not a monitor daisy chained. When I turned it off, everything worked as expected. Yay!